# Using tag helpers in Asp.Net Core 2.2 when Identity Scaffolded

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, tag-helpers

Since there is no Controller (that I can find) that governs the Account and Manage view models once you scaffold out the Identity pages in an Asp.Net Core 2.2 Web Application, how does one use the tag helpers in an anchor tag for example.

Before I could create an anchor tag as follows

```
<a id="register-button" class="submit" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a>
```

which would generate the appropriate link and when the user clicked on it, they would be taken to the registration page.

I can't see how to use these now that Identity comes from this library? How can I generate links to pages that are found in the Account and manage sections. I use these tags dozens of times in sidebar menus, header menus etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `asp-area="Identity"` to locate ASP.NET Identity area and specific which page should display :

```
<a id="ad" asp-area="Identity" class="submit" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>

<a id="ad" asp-area="Identity" class="submit" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

You can [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) to see the  existing page .